# Fastenumeration implementation

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, fast-enumeration

I am trying to implement the `countByEnumeratingWithState` method in my objective-c class (say `MyClass`
In this method I do an

```
MyOtherClass *cl = [[MyOtherClass alloc] init];
buffer[count++] = cl;
```

The reason why I have to allocate objects on the fly is because those objects are stored 'elsewhere'.
However, when using this method from an application, it will crash:

```
for (const MyOtherClass *cl in myClassObj){
    NSLog(@"obj: %@", cl.description);
}
```

The reason for this is most likely that ARC throws away my MyOtherClass object in countByEnumeratingWithState because the buffer is 'unretained'.
How can I make sure the MyOtherClass object 'retains' ?

More relevant information:

> - thread #4: tid = 0x5ca941, 0x0000000101a4cf8b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
>     frame #0: 0x0000000101a4cf8b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Let us see the buffer declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use const keyword? Const let you allocate object just for initialization and after then throw exception when you want to try change it. Try that:

```
for (MyOtherClass *cl in myClassObj){
    NSLog(@"obj: %@", cl.description);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still the same issue.

Comment: @PaulPraet can you post the stacktrace and the custom method you can see on the top of the stack.